# HTML5 drag/drop in Android

Tags: android, html, drag-and-drop

When I testing drag and drop of html5 on android, within library like Modernizr.js. I find that the test case is written as:

```
tests['draganddrop'] = function() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    return ('draggable' in div) || ('ondragstart' in div && 'ondrop' in div);
};
```

Android 2.1+ can pass this test case - draggable attribute is initialized as "false", ondragstart and ondrop are both initialized as "null".

By indeed, I can't use drag and drop in android, because never trigger drag and drop event!

I want to find the right way to know whether a mobile device support drag/dop!

Who can help me? Thank you!